# JSON expression index not being used in join under Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join

So, I have two tables in a postgresql database, one is called `foo` and is structured like so:

```
Column | Type
-------------
id     | integer
raw    | json
```

The other is called `bar` and looks like this:

```
Column | Type
-------------
id     | integer
action | character varying
```

`foo` has an index on an expression that looks like this: `"foo_expr_idx" btree ((raw ->> 'action'::text))`

This index works. Despite the fact that `foo` has millions of rows I can run a query like:

`SELECT * from foo WHERE raw->>'action' = 'open'`

And it uses the index and does not do a sequential scan. I verified this using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

However when I use that expression in a join it doesn't use the index. So a join like:

```
SELECT * from bar LEFT OUTER JOIN foo ON (bar.action = foo.raw->>'action');
```

Is hideously slow. And when I check what it's doing it's definitely doing a sequential scan. How can I make postgresql use the expression index in a join like this?

The output of explain looks like this:

```
Merge Left Join  (cost=1101140.74..1207570.52 rows=5560478 width=175)        (actual time=815671.230..873493.479 rows=16673 loops=1)
   Output: bar.id, bar.action, foo.id, foo.raw, 
   Merge Cond: ((bar.action)::text = ((foo.raw ->> 'action'::text)))
   ->  Sort  (cost=1719.29..1745.81 rows=10607 width=131) (actual  time=47.439..60.859 rows=10628 loops=1)
       Output: bar.id, bar.action
       Sort Key: bar.action
       Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1024kB
       ->  Seq Scan on public.bar  (cost=0.00..282.07 rows=10607 width=131) (actual time=0.008..10.186 rows=10628 loops=1)
           Output: bar.id, bar.action
   ->  Materialize  (cost=1099421.45..1117505.18 rows=3616747 width=44) (actual time=815623.382..864899.131 rows=3614363 loops=1)
           Output: foo.id, foo.raw, ((foo.raw ->> 'action'::text))
           ->  Sort  (cost=1099421.45..1108463.31 rows=3616747 width=44) (actual time=815623.356..851265.324 rows=3608287 loops=1)
               Output: foo.id, foo.raw, ((foo.raw ->> 'action'::text))
               Sort Key: ((foo.raw ->> 'action'::text))
               Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2611952kB
               ->  Seq Scan on public.foo  (cost=0.00..371670.47 rows=3616747 width=44) (actual time=0.052..121762.195 rows=3612522 loops=1)
                   Output: foo.id, foo.raw, (foo.raw ->> 'action'::text)
  Total runtime: 874110.670 ms
 (18 rows)
```

Comment: Please show the execution plan using `explain (analyze, verbose)`.

Comment: There are 3.6 million rows in table foo, and in reality it also has a timestamp column. I'll add the explain output now...

Comment: I've added it now, thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: Unfortunately that's the output of `explain` not `explain (analyze, verbose)`

Comment: Ah! Sorry. You want me to actually run the query. I'll update the question after lunch. It does take that long :(

Comment: Now with the output of explain. Any input greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that Postgresql was making some assumptions about the data that weren't true. The simple solution was to analyze the table...

after running

```
analyze foo;
```

My runtime for the query came down from 14 minutes to 259ms.

Comment: You also have two sort steps that are done on disk. If you increase your `work_mem` you can probably improve performance even more. Although the sort on the `foo` seems strange given the statement you have shown.